# Creating a map of constructor functions

Tags: go

So I'd like to have a map of names of functions, to choose an implementation of an interface based on an environment variable. I've reproduced it in the following code:

```
package test

type Fooer interface {
    Foo() error
}

type Bar struct{}

func NewBar() (*Bar, error) { return &Bar{}, nil }
func (b *Bar) Foo() error   { return nil }

type Baz struct{}

func NewBaz() (*Baz, error) { return &Baz{}, nil }
func (b *Baz) Foo() error   { return nil }

var constructors map[string]func() (*Fooer, error)

func init() {
    constructors = map[string]func() (*Fooer, error){
        "bar": NewBar,
        "baz": NewBaz,
    }
}
```

This throws the following errors when I `go build test.go`:

```
./test.go:21: cannot use NewBar (type func() (*Bar, error)) as type func() (*Fooer, error) in map value
./test.go:22: cannot use NewBaz (type func() (*Baz, error)) as type func() (*Fooer, error) in map value
```

So what am I doing wrong? Can I use a `*Fooer` as the return type of a constructor function? What would be the *actual* best way to approach this? (I'm new to Go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not (almost never) pass around pointers to interface. You will (almost) never need a `*Fooer`, a `Fooer` is enough.
2. Yes, your Bar and Baz constructors could return a `Fooer` (not a `*Fooer`!) but that seems awkward.
3. Keeping the constructors in a map and querying the map for a constructor seem like one level of indirection too much. Are you constantly creating new Bar and Baz?

Comment: Re 3: just once while I'm setting the configuration for a server. Need to choose which storage implementation to use.

Comment: Also, I modified it to not return a pointer, and I get the same error (module pointer, obviously.) Am I missing something?

Comment: Than a simple `var storage Fooer; if environmentWantsBaz { storage, _ = Baz{} } else { storage, _ = Bar{} }` in init should do.

Comment: Autocorrect is making me look dumb. **modulo** pointer. Without the `*` in this case.

Comment: That conditional will work fine though. I'm used to keeping things in a map, á la Python.